# Asymptotics of an integral in the coupon collector's problem

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I am interested in asymptotics of the integral $$I(h,n)=\int_0^\infty t(u) e^{-un}du$$ as $h\to \infty$ ($n$ is a fixed positive integer) where $t(u)$ is the functional inverse of the function
$$u(t)=-\ln\left(1-e^{-t}\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\dots+\frac{t^{h-1}}{(h-1)!}\right)\right). $$ This integral comes up as an expectation in the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). Based on numerical evidence, it seems that $I(h,n)$ is nearly linear in $h$. If someone could provide a quick derivation of the asymptotics of $I(h,n)$ as $h\to\infty$, that would be great.

Note that $1-e^{-t}\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\dots+\frac{t^{h-1}}{(h-1)!}\right)$ increases from $0$ to $1$ for $t\in(0,\infty)$, so this function is invertible.

Comment: Just to clarify, $u$ is of the form $$ u(x) = f(u^{-1}(x))?$$

Comment: $u$ is a function of $t$. I changed the notation to highlight this.

Comment: Is it functional or multiplicative inverse?

Comment: It's a functional inverse. $1-e^{-t}(1+t+\dots+\frac{t^{h-1}}{(h-1)!})$ increases from 0 to 1 for $t\in(0,\infty)$, so this function is invertible.

Comment: Note $u(t)=-\log P(h,t)$ where $P$ is the regularized lower incomplete gamma function. As $h\to\infty$: $u(t)\sim\log \left(\frac{h^{-h-\frac{1}{2}} t^h}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\right)+h-t$ you can simplify further.

Comment: https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.11.E5

Comment: @AaronHendrickson That looks promising, but I'd still like to see how things pan out.

Comment: By substitution : $I(h,n)=\int_0^\infty t \,\frac{P'(h,t)}{P(h,t)^{n+1}} dt$

Comment: If $X_i \sim \operatorname {Gamma}(h, 1/h)$ are independent and $X_{(n)} = \max(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, then
$$I(h, n) =
\frac h n \mathbb E(X_{(n)}), \\
\lim_{h \to \infty} \mathbb E(X_{(n)}) =
\lim_{h \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R^+} (1 - F_{X_{(n)}}(t)) \, dt =
\int_{\mathbb R^+} \lim_{h \to \infty} (1 - F_{X_i}(t)^n) \, dt = 1$$
because $1 - F_{X_{(n)}}(t)$ can be uniformly (in $h$) bounded by an integrable function and $\lim_{h \to \infty} F_{X_i}(t) = [t = 1]/2 + [t > 1]$.

Comment: @Maxim The integral turns out to be the expected number of coupons needed to make a collection of $h$ copies each of $n$ coupons. So, the asymptotic result has to be increasing in both $h$ and $n$.

Comment: Suppose $h$ is fixed and $n_1 < n_2$. Then $t(u) e^{-n_1 u} > t(u) e^{-n_2 u}$ for all $u > 0$. Therefore $n \mapsto I(h, n)$ is decreasing.

Comment: @Maxim I messed up. I left out a factor of $n^2$ in the original integral for the expectation, giving $n^2 I(h,n)\sim hn$. So, I agree more with you. That being said, computation of exact values is still different: for $n=30$, I got $n^2 I(h,n)\approx 37h$. So, there must be some significant sublinear behavior going on.

Comment: What values of $h$ are you taking? The plot of $30^2 I(h, 30)/h$ looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Msj4ybI.png).

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\exp t$ by $E$ and the $m$th partial sum of its Taylor series by $E_m$ so that \begin{align}I(h,n)&=\int_0^\infty t(1-E^{-1}E_{h-1})^n\cdot\frac d{dt}(-\log(1-E^{-1}E_{h-1}))\,dt\\&=-\int_0^\infty tE^{-n}(E-E_{h-1})^n\cdot\frac{-E^{-1}E_{h-1}+E^{-1}E_{h-2}}{1-E^{-1}E_{h-1}}\,dt\\&=\frac1{(h-1)!}\int_0^\infty t^hE^{-n}(E-E_{h-1})^{n-1}\,dt\\&=\frac1{(h-1)!}\int_0^\infty t^{hn}e^{-nt}\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{t^i}{(h+i)!}\right)^{n-1}\, dt.\end{align} Writing $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{t^i}{(h+i)!}\right)^{n-1}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_jt^j$$ such that $c_0=1/(h!)^{n-1}$ and $c_j=h!/j\sum_{k=1}^j(kn-j)c_{j-k}/(h+k)!$ for all $j>0$, we obtain \begin{align}I(h,n)&=\frac1{(h-1)!}\int_0^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_jt^{j+hn}e^{-nt}\,dt\\&=\frac1{(h-1)!}\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{c_j(j+hn)!}{n^{j+hn+1}}\\&=\frac1{(h-1)!}\left(\frac{(hn)!}{(h!)^{n-1}n^{j+hn+1}}+\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{c_j(j+hn)!}{n^{j+hn+1}}\right)\\&=\frac hn\left(\frac{(hn)!}{(h!)^nn^{hn}}+\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{c_j(j+hn)!}{n^{j+hn}h!}\right).\end{align}

Comment: Your integral is $-I(h, n)$ ($I(h, n)$ is positive). Watson's lemma is not applicable to $e^{-h t} t^{h n} g(t)$. We have $I(h, 1) = h$ and $I(h, 2) \sim h/2$, not $(n h)!/(h^{n h} (h!)^n)$.

Comment: @Maxim Thanks, Watson's lemma can't be used when $g$ also depends on $h$. I've corrected this but I'm struggling to show that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{c_j(j+hn)!}{n^{j+hn}h!}=\mathcal O(1)$. ~OP: you should unaccept my answer as it's currently partial.